# How do I gain the ability to dowse for hearts?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I was watching a friend play *Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword* the other day and saw that he can use his sword's dowsing ability to locate hearts... even though I am much further along n the game than he is, I do not have this ability. It doesn't really matter to me as I have two Heart Medals, so I am not needing to locate more hearts, I am just curious as to why he has that ability and I do not.

How do I gain the ability to dowse for hearts in *Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reach critcal health and call **Fi** by pressing D-down. After doing this once or a couple times **Fi** will tell you that you can dowse for Hearts. (You don't have to unlock additional Dowsing Targets slots before getting this one).

To get **Fi** you need to find `Goddess Sword`.

Location of `Goddess Sword` :

> The Goddess Sword is the second sword you get in Skyward Sword. It is found in the Goddess Statue in Skyloft.

[Source](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/Dowsing)

Comment: Ah ha. That's probably it. I don't stay at critical health for long and when I do, I have no time to talk to Fi! So I never called Fi while at critical health and thus never gained this ability.