# How many times do I have to call Fi before I can get the heart dowsing option

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I have asked her 5 times already and she won't give me the option. I have beaten the sand ship and have all the other extra dowsing targets, it just won't give me this one.

Comment: [Dupe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94053/how-do-i-gain-the-ability-to-dowse-for-hearts)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to actually get really low on health before she'll offer you that option. Find some enemies and take a whole bunch of damage on purpose, then try again.